# wrong message in the form.io

Tags: docker-compose, form.io

I am trying to execute formio with docker-compose, but the application is wrong.

```
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.2
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mdb-data:/data/db
    networks:
      - app-mongo
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD:

  formio:
    build: ./
    restart: always
    links:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - '3001:3001'
    volumes:
      - ./:/app:rw
    networks:
      - app-mongo
    environment:
      DEBUG: formio:*
      NODE_CONFIG: '{"mongo": "mongodb://mongo:27017/formio"}'
      ROOT_EMAIL: admin@example.com
      ROOT_PASSWORD: CHANGEME
    stdin_open: true  # -i
    tty: true         # -t
```

when i execute localhost:3001 - show me the wrong message:

```
TypeError: Could not connect to API server (Failed to fetch)
```

How to executed form.io with docker-compose?

Thanks

Comment: It's better to add fromio Dockerfile content in your question.

Comment: FROM node:lts-alpine3.10
WORKDIR /app

RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade && \
    apk add make=4.2.1-r2 && \
    apk add g++=8.3.0-r0

RUN apk --update add git

RUN git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf "ssh://git@github.com/"

Comment: ENV NPM_PACKAGES=/.npm-packages \
    PATH=$NPM_PACKAGES/bin:$PATH \
    NODE_PATH=$NPM_PACKAGES/lib/node_modules:$NODE_PATH
RUN echo "prefix = $NPM_PACKAGES" >> ~/.npmrc

COPY ./package.json $NPM_PACKAGES/
COPY ./package-lock.json $NPM_PACKAGES/
RUN npm ci --prefix=$NPM_PACKAGES
RUN apk del git
RUN ln -sf $NPM_PACKAGES/node_modules node_modules
ENV DEBUG=""
ENTRYPOINT [ "node", "main" ]

Comment: Step 8/14 : COPY ./package.json $NPM_PACKAGES/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 031cb2990d84
Step 9/14 : COPY ./package-lock.json $NPM_PACKAGES/
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat package-lock.json: file does not exist
ERROR: Service 'formio' failed to build : Build failed

Comment: above is the code dockerfile and wrong message after execute docker-compose up -d